# Webscraping - Inconsitent result due to Timeout request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some public data from website using Python 3.6.
I created a long list of pages URLs I need to scrape (10k+).
I parse each one and produce a list with all the relevant information and than I append this to a comprehensive list.

I used to get some timeout request errors so I tried to handle it using  try/except.

**The code runs without *apparent* errors but, re-running the code I get very inconsistent results: the length of the final list changes substantially and I can prove that non all the pages have been parsed.**

So my code shuts down at some point and I cannot check at what point.
the time_out variable is always zero at the end, no matter how long is the list produced.

Any help appreciated!
Best

Here is what I believe is the relevant part of the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}

LIST_OF_URLS = ['URL','URL','URL']

FINAL_LIST = []
timed_out = 0

    for URL in LIST_OF_URLS:
        try:
            result_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=headers,timeout=10).text, 'html.parser') 
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            timed_out+=1

        #The loop produces a LIST

    FINAL_LIST.append(LIST)
```

Comment: What does `LIST` do on line 16?

Comment: It is there to signify that the loop produces a list, that is than appended into final_list. It was not clear, my bad.

Comment: I'd recommend using Python's native logging libraries (`import logging`) to log information about failed HTTP requests.  Maybe your internet is going down in between requests?  It will be very hard for anyone else to be able to reliably reproduce these errors.

Comment: One of the problem was due to internet instability, and I fixed it. However the overall issue still persist. I will try to use Python's native logging libraries, as a start. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried collecting actual timed-out URLs instead of incrementing the count, and then re-crawling them?

Comment: Fixed using fake_username. The inconsistency was generated by the website shutting down after a number of requests from the same source.